# Update the column format from string to date in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I've an external table in Hive

```
Current:
col1 - string
col2 - string
col3 - string
col4 - float
col5 - int
```

I want to change the date type of col3 to date

```
Expected:
col1 - string
col2 - string
col3 - date
col4 - float
col5 - int
```

I tried regular sql command but not useful

```
alter table table_name modify col3 date;

Error:
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:32 cannot recognize input near 'modify' 'col3' 'date' in alter table statement
```

Requesting assistance here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct command is:

```
alter table table_name change col3 col3 date;
```

> The column change command will only modify Hive's metadata, and will
>   not modify data. Users should make sure the actual data layout of the
>   table/partition conforms with the metadata definition.

See syntax and manual here: [Change Column Name/Type/Position/Comment](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ChangeColumnName/Type/Position/Comment)